# How to restrict file extension when using grep with a directory parameter?

Tags: grep

```
grep -nr 'queryTag' .
```

For example, I have a number of directories in the current directory, and I want to search for the keyword 'queryTag'. However, I want to restrict the search to the file type '.txt', not all the file in the current directory. How to modify the command above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--include=` option:

```sh
grep -nr 'queryTag' --include='*.txt' .
```